# Cross Table / Tabular in R with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

## My Data

| Data | FactorA | FactorB | FactorC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| D1 | Yes | Yes | No |
| D2 | No | No | Yes |
| D1 | Weak No | No | No |
| D2 | No | Yes | No |
| D1 | Weak Yes | No | No |
| D2 | No | No | No |
| D1 | No | No | Yes |
| D2 | Weak Yes | No | No |
| D1 | Weak No | No | Yes |
| D2 | No | No | No |

## What I want

And would like to get a table like this:

| FactorA | FactorB | FactorC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| No | 1 | 2 |
| Weak No | 0 | 1 |
| Weak Yes | 0 | 0 |
| Yes | 1 | 0 |

which counts the pairwise co-occurances of each level of `FactorA` with "Yes" of `FactorB` and `FactorC`. Preferably once, overall and grouped by `Data`.

## What I have

```
df %>% 
    group_by(Dataset) %>%
    group_by(FactorA, FactorB) %>% 
    summarise(num = n()) %>%
    spread(FactorB, num)
```

which return

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   FactorA [4]
  FactorA    No   Yes
  <fct>         <int> <int>
1 No             1092    36
2 Weakly No       684    NA
3 Weakly Yes     2388    60
4 Yes            9660   216
```

(numbers in output are taken from the real data, not toy data)

## Question

Is there a sleek way to get the table I want with multiple Factors in `dplyr` style s.t. I can simply split it by `Data` later.

Comment: May you `dput` some sample data to make it easier for others to help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`group_by` `FactorA` and count number of `Yes` in `FactorB` and `FactorC` columns.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(FactorA) %>%
  summarise(across(FactorB:FactorC, ~sum(. == 'Yes')))

#  FactorA  FactorB FactorC
#* <chr>      <int>   <int>
#1 No             1       2
#2 Weak No        0       1
#3 Weak Yes       0       0
#4 Yes            1       0
```

Comment: I think using `across(.cols = contains("Factor"), ~sum(. == 'Yes'))` could be better in case there would be more Factor than `FactorB` & `FactorC`

Answer (score 0):

**1) Base R** Compare each of the columns except the first two to Yes and grouping that by the second column sum them.  The result is the following one-liner. No packages are used.   It ran nearly 3x faster than a dplyr solution when I benchmarked it.

```
# column 1 is Data, column 2 is FactorA, rest are other factors
aggregate(DF[-(1:2)] == "Yes", DF[2], sum)
```

giving:

```
   FactorA FactorB FactorC
1       No       1       2
2  Weak No       0       1
3 Weak Yes       0       0
4      Yes       1       0
```

**2) collapse** A similar approach which likely runs faster is to use collap in the collapse package.  It ran 19x faster than a dplyr solution when I benchmarked it.

```
library(collapse)

collap(+(slt(DF, FactorB:FactorC) == "Yes"), DF$FactorA, fsum)
```

giving:

```
   FactorA FactorB FactorC
1       No       1       2
2  Weak No       0       1
3 Weak Yes       0       0
4      Yes       1       0
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form:

```
DF <- structure(list(Data = c("D1", "D2", "D1", "D2", "D1", "D2", "D1", 
"D2", "D1", "D2"), FactorA = c("Yes", "No", "Weak No", "No", 
"Weak Yes", "No", "No", "Weak Yes", "Weak No", "No"), FactorB = c("Yes", 
"No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), FactorC = c("No", 
"Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Answer (score 0):

**base**

```r
df <- structure(list(Data = c("D1", "D2", "D1", "D2", "D1", "D2", "D1", 
                              "D2", "D1", "D2"), FactorA = c("Yes", "No", "Weak No", "No", 
                                                             "Weak Yes", "No", "No", "Weak Yes", "Weak No", "No"), FactorB = c("Yes", 
                                                                                                                               "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), FactorC = c("No", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                   "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  -10L))



sapply(df[3:4], function(x) table(df$FactorA, x)[, 2])
#>          FactorB FactorC
#> No             1       2
#> Weak No        0       1
#> Weak Yes       0       0
#> Yes            1       0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>